# know type of variable in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I identify the type of variable in Swift. For e.g. if I write

`struct RandomStruct....` - the type should give me `struct` and not `RandomStruct`

or if I write `class RandomClass...` the type should be `class` and not `RandomClass`.

I have tried using `Mirror.subjectType` and `type(of:)` both of which gives output as `RandomStruct` and `RandomClass`

Comment: You misunderstand what "type" means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close with use of [`Mirror`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror): you can look at the [`displayStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror/1538870-displaystyle) property (of enum type [`Mirror.DisplayStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror.displaystyle)) of the `Mirror` reflecting upon an instance of your type

```
struct Foo {}
class Bar {}

let foo = Foo()
let bar = Bar()

if let displayStyle = Mirror(reflecting: foo).displayStyle {
    print(displayStyle) // struct
}

if let displayStyle = Mirror(reflecting: bar).displayStyle {
    print(displayStyle) // class
}
```

Just note that `.optional` is also a case of the `DisplayStyle` enum of `Mirror`, so be sure to reflect on concrete (unwrapped) types:

```
struct Foo {}

let foo: Foo? = Foo()

if let displayStyle = Mirror(reflecting: foo as Any).displayStyle {
    // 'as Any' to suppress warnings ...
    print(displayStyle) // optional
}
```

Comment: Thank-you. I missed that by a whisker :-)

Comment: @prabodhprakash you would've probably stumpled over it yourself in two more whiskers :) happy to help

Answer (score -3):

You can check with this way;

```
if let randomClass = controlClass as? RandomClass {
   /* Codes */
}
```

You can understand with this way, your variable which kind of class.

Comment: He wants to understand the structure, not the type of the class itself.